# How to fetch mp3 file from zipped expansion file?

Tags: android, file, mp3, expansion

I'm trying to access some mp3 files from my expansion file. I've added the following three libraries to my projects

download_library
licencing library
zip_file

I've tried most solutions and nothing seems to budge. Perhaps I'm missing out on some important steps? Can someone hook me up with the basic code on how I can read a mp3 file from my zipped expansion file?

Here's the name of my expansion file which has been zipped up without any compression:
 main.1.com.ibyteapps.joecharlie.obb

The files in this zipped file are aa.mp3, bb.mp3, cc.mp3 and so on. The total number of mp3 files I have exceed the base size of 50MB. Hence I need an expansion file.

Also, whenever I write a code like

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = new ZipResourceFile(myPath);
```

I keep getting an error saying "surround with IO block". Why is this so? Can I not do it without the IO block if I perform all of my checks properly?

I keep getting the following errors when I run the app on my android phone:

[2013-08-14 10:49:54 - downloader_library] Could not find downloader_library.apk!
[2013-08-14 10:49:54 - library] Could not find library.apk!
[2013-08-14 10:49:54 - zip_file] Could not find zip_file.apk!

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
    try {
        expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(getBaseContext(),
                1, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("mysample.mp3");
```

Next step, implementing the downloader service.. if anyone has any plain and simple instructions.